# Quality Center Microsoft Excel Add-in Error

Tags: excel, add-in, hp-quality-center

I work on Mercury Quality Center 8.2 Build 3406 Entreprise Edition.

In order to write tests within Excel for Test Director, I installed the Excel Add-In.
 When I try to export the Excel file to Quality Center I get the following message

> Quality Center Microsoft Excel Add-in Error
>
> A general error has occured. Restart Microsoft Excel. Class does not support Automation or expected interface'.

I use Excel 2003 (11.5612.5606) part of MS Office Professional Edition 2003.

Could someone tell me how to make work this add-in correctly ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Try below steps:**

> Launch MS Excel 2010
> Go to Option--> Trus Center -->Trus Center Settings --> Protected View --> Uncheck the Enable Data Execution Prevention Mode
> Restart the Excel.

**Still facing the problem:**

> Navigate to Addins page in QC
>
> Click on "HP ALM Client Registration" and run "Register HP ALM Client"
>
> Close and re-start the Excel program.

Comment: I am not able to login, working with Excel 2013 & HP QC 11.5. Please help